# Flutter how get all data on return List<Widget>?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a widget and I want to return all the data I pulled from firestore there. I want to sort all the data I returned in one page, one under the other, in the Text() widget.

```
Widget getCustomerRepairLogDate() {
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
late final _repairLogs =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get();
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _repairLogs,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<Widget> items = [];
      final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
      if (data == null) return Text("got null");

      for (final eleman in data) {
        if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
          items.add(Text("${eleman.data()['dateTime']}"));
        }
      }
      return ListView(children: items);
      // return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `items` and the `children` of a `Row` like so:

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _repairLogs,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<Widget> items = [];
      final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
      if (data == null) return Text("got null");

      for (final eleman in data) {
        if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
          items.add(Text("${eleman.data()['description']}"));
        }
      }
      return Row(children: [Icon(Icons.add), ...items]);
      
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  });
```

Comment: So, how can I use it on the page? When I use getCustomerRepairlog() it is get empty.

Comment: Where's `getCustomerRepairlog` from and where did you use it?

Comment: sorry, my bad. i edited post. I am using it in Row widget.

Comment: Instead of using a `ListView`, use a `Row`, I've made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, its worked. But I cant put any widget before the items in the row. For example, how can I do this as Row(Icon, items) ?

Comment: You can use the spread operator, `...` with the items, I made an edit, please check.

Comment: well, title is a String. But when I want to get an array, how can I return the elements of the array? For example, I did something like:

for (final eleman in data) {
            if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
              for (final item in eleman.data()['title']) {
                items.add(Text("${eleman.data()['title'][item]}"));
              }
              
            }
          }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ok, no problem, i did it. Thank you.